# Cargar imagen desde página y guardar en una Base de Datos (MySQL)

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

He intentado ver la forma de cargar una imagen desde una página web con `php`, pero los comandos estan obsoletos y no estan actualizados.

Mi código es:

`index.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Subir Imagen PHP</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Tutorial, subir imagen a base de datos</h1>
  <form action="pagina2.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <label> Ingrese el Producto</label>
    <input type="text" name="producto" required>
    <br>
    <label>Seleccione su imagen que desea subir</label>
    <input type="file" name="imagen" required>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="Enviar">

  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

`pagina2.php`:

```
<?php
include"conectar.php";
conectarBD();
$producto=$_REQUEST['producto'];
$nombreimg=$_FILES['imagen']['name'];//Obtiene el nombre
$archivo=$_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'];//Contiene el archivo
$ruta="images";
$ruta=$ruta."/".$nombreimg; ///images/nombre.jpg

move_uploaded_file($archivo, $ruta);
$query=mysql_query("insert into productos values('','".$producto."','".$ruta."')");

if($query){
    echo "Insertado Correctamente";
} else {
    echo "Error al insertar";
}


?>
```

`conectar.php`:

```
<?php

function conectarBD(){

$cons_usuario="root";
$cons_contra="";
$cons_base_datos="test";
$cons_equipo="localhost";

$conex = mysqli_connect($cons_equipo,$cons_usuario,$cons_contra,$cons_base_datos);
    if(!$conex){
        die("Error: ".mysql_error());
    }
    $database=mysql_select_db("test",$conex);
    if(!$database){
        die("Error: ".mysql_error());
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Ten mucho cuidado. Estás mezclando las funciones obsoletas `mysql_*` con las nuevas `mysqli_*`. Probablemente no te funcionará la consulta por ese tema.

Comment: PD: Estoy redactando una respuesta, se demorará bastante porque hay muchos cambios que proponer.

Answer (score 1):

El principal problema que veo en tu código es la mezcla que haces entre las funciones obsoletas [`mysql_*`](https://www.php.net/es/book.mysql) y las nuevas [`mysqli_*`](https://www.php.net/es/book.mysqli).

Para corregirlo debes cambiar en `conectar.php`:

```
<?php
function conectarBD() {
  $cons_usuario = "root";
  $cons_contra = "";
  $cons_base_datos = "test";
  $cons_equipo = "localhost";
  $conex = mysqli_connect(
    $cons_equipo,
    $cons_usuario,
    $cons_contra,
    $cons_base_datos
  );  
  if ($conex === false) {
    /* Este error en particular está en mysqli_connect_error() */
    die("Error: " . mysqli_connect_error());
  }
  /* No es necesario seleccionar base de datos */
  /* Devolvemos la conexión, es necesaria para realizar consultas */
  return $conex;
}
/* No es necesario cerrar PHP si el archivo contiene únicamente código */
```

En el archivo `pagina2.php`:

```
<?php
include 'conectar.php';
/* Cuando llamemos a la función debemos quedarnos con la conexión */
$conex = conectarBD();
/* Procura evitar el uso de variables intermediarias */
$ruta = "images/" . $_FILES['imagen']['name'];
/* Movemos el archivo temporal al destino (sobreescribiendo el anterior) */
move_uploaded_file(
  $_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'],
  $ruta
);
/* Realizamos la consulta SQL escapando el contenido de las variables */
$query = mysqli_query(
  $conex,
  "
    INSERT INTO productos
    VALUES (
      '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['producto']) . "',
      '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($ruta) . "'
    )
  "
);

if ($query !== false) {
  die("Insertado Correctamente");
} else {
  die("Error al insertar: " . mysqli_error($conex));
}
```

He de advertirte que tu código sufre de los [graves problemas de seguridad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpKIhF7naSY) asociados a la [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL). Debes solucionarlos con consultas preparadas o usando [`mysqli::real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysqli.real-escape-string). En mi respuesta he optado por usar `mysqli_real_escape_string()`.

Además, te recomiendo hacer comprobaciones en el nombre del archivo o forzarlo mediante, por ejemplo, el uso de un picadillo en el nombre o raíz para evitar que te inyecten archivos PHP u otros no deseados o, incluso, sobrescriban archivos previamente subidos.